# How to pass property to modal in ASP.NET MVC Razor view?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a razor view as below C# ASP.NET MVC. This view populate summary rows for transaction on a bank account per day. User can clicks each row to view details of each day. When user click each row a modal appears and user select to see details about payments or receptions.

My problem is the link to view these details in modal are related to date clicked by user so I need to generate link when modal appears and it is not known before rendering view in server side.

I know that I can handle this situation using jQuery and ajax but since I have no knowledge about front-end I don't know how to handle this situation.

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.BankAccountDailySummary>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BankAccountDailySummary";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="wrapper">


    <!-- Content Wrapper -->
    <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column fadeInRight animated faster">
        <!-- Main Content -->

        <div id="content">
            <!-- Topbar -->
            <div class=" sticky-top ios-content-box-header p-1">
                <nav class="topbar  container-fluid pr-16p">
                    <div class="row font-12 " style="height: 45px">
                        <div class="col-3 text-right m-auto color-orange pl-1 pr-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-6 px-1 text-center m-auto text-gray-900 f-w-600 text-overflow-dot">@ViewBag.accountName</div>
                        <div class="col-3 text-left m-auto color-orange pr-1 pl-1"><a href="bank.html" class="ios-nav-link"> return<i class="fas fa-chevron-left  fa-fw  mr-1 color-orange"></i></a></div>
                    </div>

                </nav>

            </div>
            <!-- End of Topbar -->
            <!-- Begin Page Content -->
            <div class="container-fluid px-0 head-foot-margin min-h-content">
                <!-- Page Heading -->

                <form class="user" action="">


                    <span class="col-12 text-gray-900 font-12  d-inline-block  px-4 pb-2 ">Time interval</span>
                    <div class="ios-content-box px-4 py-3 mb-3 sticky-top" style="top:49px">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <a href="#" class="col-1 p-0"><i class="fas fa-search  fa-fw  m-auto d-block  text-gray-500 pt-2"></i></a>
                            <div class="form-group float-right  col-4 input-style-1">
                                <input title="" id="dateValue_1" type="text" class="example1 form-control form-control-user d-inline" />
                            </div>
                            <a onclick="clearValue('dateValue_1')" class="col-1 p-0"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt  fa-fw  m-auto d-block  text-gray-500 pt-2"></i></a>
                            <div class="form-group float-right  col-4 input-style-1">
                                <input title="" id="dateValue_2" type="text" class="example1 form-control form-control-user d-inline" />
                            </div>
                            <a onclick="clearValue('dateValue_2')" class="col-1 p-0"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt  fa-fw  m-auto d-block  text-gray-500 pt-2"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" date =" @item.Date">
                                <div class="ios-content-box px-4 py-1 mb-3 ios-hover-box">
                                    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
                                        <div class="col-10 f-w-600 color-orange text-right">@ViewBag.accountName</div>
                                        <div class="col-2 text-left"> <i class="fas fa-chevron-left  fa-fw  color-orange "></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
                                        <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-right">Receptions</div>
                                        <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-left digit_divider">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalPayment)</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
                                        <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-right">Payments</div>
                                        <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-left digit_divider">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalReception)</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
                                        <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-right">Remaining</div>
                                        <div class="col-6 text-gray-900 f-w-600 text-left digit_divider">>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Remain)</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        }@*foreach item*@
                    }@*if model was not null*@


                </form>


            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
            <div class=" sticky-top ios-content-box-footer p-1" style="bottom: 0">
                <nav class="bottom-bar  container-fluid pr-15p" style="height: 40px;">
                    <div class="row font-12 " style="height: 40px">
                        <div class="col-6 text-right m-auto text-gray-900">Total items found: </div>
                        <div class="col-6 d-inline m-auto  color-orange text-left">@ViewBag.itemCount</div>
                    </div>

                </nav>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Main Content -->
    </div>
    <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-top: 50%">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header border-0 ">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="z-index: 10">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title modal-title-ios font-13 f-w-600 text-gray-900">Select Type of Report:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class=" w-100 " style="overflow: auto">

                        <div class="row justify-content-center m-0">

                            <div class=" col-6 col-sm-4 text-center mb-2"><a href="@Url.Action("BankAccountDailyDeatils","Banks",new {accountId =  @ViewBag.accountID,date= "dateReadFromROW", isPayment=true, accountName= ViewBag.accountName})" class="ios-nav-link text-gray-900"><div class=" bg-white border shadow-sm border-radius-10 home-items p-3"><img src="~/assets/icons/debit-card.svg" class="max-w-55 m-auto"><div class="font-12 mt-2">Payments</div></div></a></div>
                            <div class=" col-6 col-sm-4 text-center mb-2"><a href="@Url.Action("BankAccountDailyDeatils","Banks",new {accountId =  @ViewBag.accountID,date= "dateReadFromROW",isPayment=false, accountName= ViewBag.accountName})" class="ios-nav-link text-gray-900"><div class=" bg-white border shadow-sm border-radius-10 home-items p-3"><img src="~/assets/icons/income.svg" class="max-w-55 m-auto"><div class="font-12 mt-2">Receptions</div></div></a></div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
<!-- End of Page Wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to do with jQuery(I hope that your modal comes from bootstrap framework).
You just have to subscribe to show modal event, fetch the date parameter from the pressed link, generate full links and populate modal links' href attributes.
You might find [this docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) helpfull.

```js
// define base link url(without date parameter)
var testLink = '/Banks/BankAccountDailyDeatils?accountId=1&accountName=test';//just for display purposes, you should use generated link as a base url
var link = '@Url.Action("BankAccountDailyDeatils", "Banks", new { accountId = ViewBag.accountID, accountName = ViewBag.accountName })';//perhaps it must be encoded properly

//subscribe to the show modal event
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  //retrieve pressed button from the event
  var button = $(e.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  //retrieve the date parameter from the button
  var date = button.data('date'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
  //populate links' href attributes
  $('#paymentsLink').attr('href', testLink + '&isPayment=true&date=' + date);
  $('#receptionsLink').attr('href', testLink + '&isPayment=false&date=' + date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-date="2019-12-12">
  <div class="ios-content-box px-4 py-1 mb-3 ios-hover-box">
    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
      <div class="col-10 f-w-600 color-orange text-right">@ViewBag.accountName</div>
      <div class="col-2 text-left"> <i class="fas fa-chevron-left  fa-fw  color-orange "></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-right">Receptions</div>
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-left digit_divider">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalPayment)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-right">Payments</div>
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-left digit_divider">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalReception)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-right">Remaining</div>
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-900 f-w-600 text-left digit_divider">>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Remain)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-date="2020-01-14">
  <div class="ios-content-box px-4 py-1 mb-3 ios-hover-box">
    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
      <div class="col-10 f-w-600 color-orange text-right">@ViewBag.accountName</div>
      <div class="col-2 text-left"> <i class="fas fa-chevron-left  fa-fw  color-orange "></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-right">Receptions</div>
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-left digit_divider">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalPayment)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-right">Payments</div>
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-left digit_divider">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalReception)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row font-12 my-2 ios-divider-line">
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-600 text-right">Remaining</div>
      <div class="col-6 text-gray-900 f-w-600 text-left digit_divider">>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Remain)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-top: 50%">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header border-0 ">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="z-index: 10">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h5 class="modal-title modal-title-ios font-13 f-w-600 text-gray-900">Select Type of Report:</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class=" w-100 " style="overflow: auto">

          <div class="row justify-content-center m-0">

            <div class=" col-6 col-sm-4 text-center mb-2">
              <a href="#" id="paymentsLink">
                <div class=" bg-white border shadow-sm border-radius-10 home-items p-3"><img src="~/assets/icons/debit-card.svg" class="max-w-55 m-auto">
                  <div class="font-12 mt-2">Payments</div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-6 col-sm-4 text-center mb-2">
              <a href="#" id="receptionsLink" class="ios-nav-link text-gray-900">
                <div class=" bg-white border shadow-sm border-radius-10 home-items p-3"><img src="~/assets/icons/income.svg" class="max-w-55 m-auto">
                  <div class="font-12 mt-2">Receptions</div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The Boostrap document link was so useful and informative